# Place images relative to each other based on where they were shot

Tags: image-processing

Suppose I take multiple 360 photos of a room from various locations but from the same height, how can I place them relative to each other?

Ex.
1 - x - 2
x - 3 - x
4 - 5 - x

If I shot the photos at 1, 2, 3, 4 and 5 is there any algorithm which can correctly place the images relative to each other by just analyzing them?

Comment: Are you trying to group all photos taken from the same location together, or to identify the location a photo was taken from, or to arrange the photos in a grid according to where they were taken from? Is it just their relative arrangement that is important, or also their absolute location?

Comment: Are these "360 photos" 360 degree panoramic photographs, looking horizontally in all directions? Or are they spherical photographs, looking in all directions, including up and down as well as horizontally?

Comment: I have put the question on hold until it can be clarified. Once it has been edited to make clear what is provided and what is required, it can be reopened if it is on topic.

Comment: @trichoplax Yes. All the photos were taken in the same room. I want to arrange them in their absolute location. These are spherical photos.

Comment: If you're not sure how to edit the wording to make clear what you want, feel free to drop into [chat].